# Are digital services taxable?

Tags: taxes, services

I need your help. I wonder if someone with a European based company, offer's a digital service from a website and have clients from all over the world (US-EU-ASIA etc.), should apply taxes when collects payments? Then those taxes should differs from client's country to client's country and if yes then where you pay back this taxes. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I suppose, only pay taxes in a foreign country if the company has an office in that country.

Comment: @Spring Thank you. But what about additional taxes on sale. For example when you sell in Europe you should include VAT or in united states US sales tax

Comment: Keep a financial reserve so that a ruling against the company doesn't wipe-it-out.

Comment: It depends on the laws at both ends. You might need to check each jurisdiction that you do business in separately.